# How to exceed problems Import.io has with websites that has more JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, prerender, import.io

Recently I found import.io as extremely useful tool and started to play with it, but very fast I realized it has significant problems in work with websites that has a lot of JavaScript code. import.io offers another tool [Prerender](http://support.import.io/knowledgebase/articles/623235-infinite-scroll-and-javascript-prerender-beta) (currently in Beta phase) that tries to solve such problems by converting websites with JavaScript to plain HTML, but it still cannot convert many websites in proper way.

As I would extremely like to continue to use import.io could you help me how I could use it for following website (that is just one of examples that I tried):

http://www.rentalcars.com/SearchResults.do?dropCity=Podgorica&doMinute=0&location=382046&driversAge=25&doHour=10&searchType=&locationName=Aerodrom+Podgorica&doFiltering=false&puSameAsDo=on&city=Podgorica&puHour=10&dropCountryCode=&dropCountry=Crna+Gora&puDay=10&filterTo=1000&dropLocation=382046&driverage=on&doDay=17&countryCode=&dropLocationName=Aerodrom+Podgorica&country=Crna+Gora&enabler=&filterFrom=0&puMonth=12&puMinute=0&doMonth=12&doYear=2015&puYear=2015&fromLocChoose=true&filterName=CarCategorisationSupplierFilter

Also, if there is another tool (like Prerender) that could convert website with JavaScript to plain HTML, please suggest! In that way, I could try to use it together with import.io.

Thanks in advance!

Nemanja

Comment: Question about finding resources are offtopic on stackoverflow. Why not trying softwarerecommendations.stackexchange?

Comment: @Trilarion My question is firstly related to appropriate way of using current tool, i.e. to solution of current problem, and because of that it can be posted here. If I wanted just to switch to another tool, I agree that better place would be softwarerecommendations.

Comment: You are right in that you not only ask for a library. You also ask about using a certain tool. If this tool is not used primarily for programming though it is still offtopic. You might be better off at superuser.stackexchange then.

Comment: @Trilarion I understand your point, but in that case, most of import.io questions should be off-topic, even it would not be good solution... I don't see any difference in purpose from following questions that are active: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694562/data-crawling-using-import-io http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641773/import-io-stuck-at-initializing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32141516/data-crawler-or-something-else

Comment: That is probably an inconsistency of Stackoverflow although maybe import.io is seen as a programming tool. Not sure..

Answer (score 2):

> that tries to solve such problems by converting websites with JavaScript to plain HTML...

Import.io is a free tool, therefore it's designed for scrape of low to middle complexity websites. It sure could not resolve all on-page JS stuffing.

> it still cannot convert many websites in proper way

The main point is that even if you success with prerendring a webpage into pure HTML, some pages' logic might still require *further (after page load) JS operations* (ex.: [artificial] form submissions, xhr calls, event handlers outwork and etc.). You better scrape using other tools that might drive a web browser instance that will handle all these fine operations.
Ex. [Selenium](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/), [Content Grabber](https://webscraping.pro/content-grabber-review/) (operating in the full browser mode), [CloudScrape](https://webscraping.pro/cloudscrape-review/), PyQt and others.